# Google search return Azure website domain

Tags: asp.net, azure

I have an ASP.NET MVC website deployed on Azure. I have configured Azure to point to my custom Domain and also I have configured Azure IIS to return a 301 so that every search should return to my custom Domain.
The redirect inside ASP.NET MVC is configured as following:

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Disable Azure Domain" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
          <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="*.azurewebsites.net" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.oxytechs.com{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
```

Unfortunately, if I Google for "OXY SmartWatch" I get back my Azure domain while with Bing I get back my custom domain. What should I do in order to never return, crawl or index the Azure domain? I also configured Google Webmaster tools and Bing Webmaster tools but the problem is still showing up on Google search.

Comment: Give it a few weeks for Google to re-spider your website.

Comment: Is there any chance to force a re-spider of my website all over "Google", "Bing" and "Yahoo"?